# angular material get value of the checked checkbox by using form group and formarray

Tags: checkbox, angular-material

I want to generate checkbox with an array

> component.ts

```
profiles: string[] = [
    'Sales Admin',
    'Finance Admin',
    'Gateway Admin',
    'Support Admin',
  ];
profileControls: any;

//creating formcontrols
constructor() {    
    this.profileControls = this.profiles.map(c => new FormControl(false));
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
  }

createFormControls() {    
    this.userid = new FormControl('', Validators.email);
    this.accsprofile = new FormArray(this.profileControls);
}

createForm() {
    this.myform = new FormGroup({      
      userid: this.userid,      
      accsprofile: this.accsprofile
    });
  }
```

> component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let profile of profileControls let i=index" >
    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [formControlName]="profiles[i]">
      {{profiles[i]}}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

the output is showing false though i check all check-boxes. I want to get the value of the check-boxes which are checked

> output
>   [image]

Comment: You shouldn't use ngModel and forms on the same component. My guess is that's your problem.

Comment: @Tranter,  no not working.

Comment: What isn't working? You haven't stated what you tried.

Comment: @Tranter, I shared the above written component code, html code. I checked all checkboxes but, the output is showing false for all of them.

Comment: The code still uses both ngModel and formControlName. Don't do that.

Comment: @Tranter, I finished it by creating individual check-boxes as I could not solve the above issue. Please help if you have free time. TQ